# Loading data into Google Big Query with a timezone

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking to analyse electricity demand and market pricing, data that is published by the energy market operator here in Australia

The data is CSV and has the following schema. I *think* that times are local ie allow for daylight savings clock changes

"Date","Time","TOTALDEMAND","RRP"

01/01/10,00:30:00,7809.31,21.5

IIUC to allow for the changes to/from daylight savings, I need to use Timestamp, so I combined the first two data fields

"Timestamp","TOTALDEMAND","RRP"

01/01/10 00:30:00,7809.31,21.5

and then I looked at the BQ docs to see how I tell it what timezone the data is for. This is where it breaks. I've tried what seems every combination of

2021-09-01T00:00:00 Australia/Sydney

2021-09-01 00:00:00 Australia/Sydney

and the only one that works is if I use UTC, but I'm not in UTC

2021-09-01 00:00:00 UTC

Any ideas?

TIA

PS apologies for the ident style, the formatter won't let me use a simple cariage return, that I can see

ShinySteve

Answer (score 0):

Try `2021-09-01 00:00:00.000 +11:00`

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#data_types

> BigQuery accepts a variety of timestamp formats. The timestamp must
> include a date portion and a time portion.
>
> - The date portion can be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD.
> - The timestamp portion must be formatted as HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]    (seconds and fractions of seconds are optional).
> - The date and time must be separated by a space or 'T'.
> - Optionally, the date and time can be followed by a UTC offset or the    UTC zone designator (Z). For more information, see Time zones.
>
> For example, any of the following are valid timestamp values:
>
> - 2018-08-19 12:11
> - 2018-08-19 12:11:35
> - 2018-08-19 12:11:35.22
> - 2018/08/19 12:11
> - 2018-07-05 12:54:00 UTC
> - 2018-08-19 07:11:35.220 -05:00
> - 2018-08-19T12:11:35.220Z
>
> If you provide a schema, BigQuery also accepts Unix Epoch time for
> timestamp values. However, schema autodetection will not detect this
> case, and will treat the value as a numeric or string type instead.
>
> Examples of Unix Epoch timestamp values:
>
> - 1534680695
> - 1.534680695e11

Comment: I considered +11:00 but that's only tru for 1/2 the year. Likewise if I used +10:00 again only correct 1/2 the year